# Laravel 5.1 passing data to partial

Tags: php, laravel

I have a controller where I get the unread comments on the projects of the logged in user. Now my problem is I need this data in my nav partial to show it on all my views. But unfortunately this does not work.

Here's my route:

```
Route::get('/', 'KlantController@getUnreads');
```

Here's my function in my KlantController

```
public function getUnreads(){
        $uid = Auth::user()->id;
        $projects = User::find($uid)->projects;

        //comments
        if (!empty($projects)) {
            foreach ($projects as $project) {     
                $comments_collection[] = $project->comments;
            }
        }

        if (!empty($comments_collection)) {
            $comments = array_collapse($comments_collection);
            $unreads = collect($comments)->where('unread', "1")->count();
        }
        return view('partials.nav', $unreads);
    }
```

And here's where I use the data in my partial.

```
@if($unreads > 0)
  <span class="label label-danger">{{ $unreads }}</span>
@endif
```

Annoying enough this gives me multiple times the following error:

```
Undefined variable: unreads (View: /var/www/resources/views/partials/nav.blade.php)
```

Anyone has any idea how I can fix this? Any help is appreciated!

Many thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

The data you are passing should be an array with key/value pairs.

From the [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/views#passing-data-to-views):

> When passing information in this manner, $data should be an array with
>   key/value pairs. Inside your view, you can then access each value
>   using its corresponding key

In your case, you can just use the [`compact`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php) function.

```
return view('partials.nav', compact('unreads'));
```

Comment: define your function as `public function getUnreads($unreads=0)`. Because if there are not any comments, unreads variable is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

I am working currently for one client in Laravel 5.1 (*YES, I know please don't ask*).

Anyways to help somebody perhaps.

In the controller:

```
public function blogIndex()
{
    $posts = Blog::orderBy('date')
        ->where('status', 'Published')
        ->whereDate('date', '<', Carbon::now())
        ->paginate(10);

    return view('pages.blog.index', compact('posts'));
}
```

In one of the views, we have partial.

```
@include('partials.blog-categories-nav', ['posts' => $posts]);
```

In that partial `resources/views/partials/blog-categories-nav.blade.php`

```
{{ dd($posts) }}
```

The output clearly you get:

[image: Did and Dump]

Perhaps, just perhaps you guys forgot to include `{{ }}`, curly brackets or perhaps `$` in `$var`.

If for some reason it is NOT still working, you can always use `{{ dd(get_defined_vars()) }}` in views.

Which will output all of your variables in for us well known *die and dump* `dd` format.

Cheers hope this will help someone;

I wish you happy coding.

Have a nice day my fellow developers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

In your function:

```
return view('partials.nav', ['unreads' => $unreads]);
```

In your view:

```
@if(count($unreads) > 0)
  @foreach ($unreads as $unread)
     <span class="label label-danger">{{ $unread }}</span>
  @endforeach
@endif
```

Comment: This doesn't work unfortunately, I still get the same error :(

Comment: Yep, I do. I get it 3 times actually. I think it is because I have 3 comments in my database

Comment: Hum....
In your if, use the count function @if(count($unreads) > 0). And I think that maybe you should use a @foreach because your $unreads variable is an array.

Comment: can't be an array it's just a ->count()

Comment: Nope still don't work :'( same error. I think something is wrong with my route maybe?

Answer (score 0):

```
return view('partials.nav')->with(['unreads' => $unreads]);
```

And in your controller, you can start it this way:

```
$uid = Auth::user()->id;
$projects = User::find($uid)->projects;
$unreads = 0
```

So, if theres no comments, the $unreads vars will exists in your view anyway.